# logic gates. What makes it what it is?

Tags: logic-gates, electron

Does anyone know what it is about each logic gate that makes it "and, or not xand, etc." like, is it a different shape, therefore causing electrons to go different places when a charge is applied through it? As in I'd like to know what they look like under a microscope to know why a gate is what it is. Thanks

Comment: perhaps you can start reading introductory material of Digital IC design and CMOS inverter.

Comment: Logic gates are circuits constructed using electronic switch devices such as transistors. The fundamental behavior and construction of those devices is explained by semiconductor physics. You need to study that first and then study how individual switching devices are combined to make there various types of logic gates. The question is too broad to be explained as an answer to a question here. I am voting to close the question.

Comment: that is the information I was looking for. thanks a lot 

Comment: See [Widipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resistor%E2%80%93transistor_logic).

Answer (score 6):

The levels of abstraction are gate -> transistor -> silicon.

A NOT gate at the transistor level might looks like this:

[image: schematic]

If you think of a logic TRUE or HI input voltage as pushing button, and a logic FALSE or LO input voltage as releasing the button then the NMOS can be conceptualized as an normally-open pushbutton and the PMOS as a normally-closed pushbutton. If the two transistors have their inputs/gates (or base if BJT transistors are used) that is the same as mechanically ganging the pushbuttons together so that pushing a button pushes multiple buttons simultaneously.

[image: schematic]

Or you can think of the NMOS as a normally open relay and a PMOS as a normally closed relay, with a powered coil has a logic TRUE/HI voltage input and an unpowered coil as a logic FALSE/LO voltage input.

You can use this concept to easily see how the logic circuit is behave if you are not very familiar with transistors.

Once you wrap your mind around it a bit, the easier way you can think of it is that an NMOS blocks current when the gate is a LO voltage and conducts current when the gate is a HI voltage. A PMOS is opposite where the PMOS conducts current when the gate is LO voltage and blocks current when the gate is a HI voltage.

**NOTE:** This is a vast simplification and ignores a lot of requirements to get a MOSFETs to behave this way in a real circuit, so if you actually try to build a circuit using these rules alone without knowing these quirks, the circuit will almost certainly not work. One quirk, for example, can be seen in how the PMOS is only ever used on the top-side with the source-terminal connected to +V, and the NMOS is only ever used on the low-side with the source-terminal connected to GND. Whereas, relays or pushbuttons behave the same no matter where they are positioned in a  circuit.

---

A NOR gate at the transistor level might look like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXFvWR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

A NAND gate at the transistor level might looks like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1hBxf.png)</sup>

From here, you can turn the NAND/NOR gate into an AND/OR gate by chaining a NOT gate to the end of it.

And each MOSFET that makes up the gate circuitry in physical silicon might look like this (there are different ways to physically arrange things for different optimizations):

[image]

[image]

Taken from: https://encyclopedia2.thefreedictionary.com/MOSFET

Under an electron microscope they might look like this from above:
[image]
Taken from: https://davidabergel.wordpress.com/2017/02/22/transistor/

But the cross section under an electron microscope might look like this:
[image]
Taken from: https://venturebeat.com/2012/09/23/samsung-making-apple-a6/

Comment: great post thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

A logic gate is a circuit based on transistors. You can Google each of these gate types and look up the underlying circuit.

The shape is important, but not the way your question implies. You hook up your tv to your entertainment center using cables that connect specific ports on each device. The pins of a transistor are like those ports. It doesn't matter if your tv is on the floor or mounted using a wall arm. In like manner the circuit is the same, but what it looks like under a microscope can very based on implementation, manufacturing techniques, power requirements etc.

A quick Google gives me this link: [AND Gate Tutorial](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/logic/logic_2.html)
You'll see each schematic and learn why it works the way it does.

Comment: will do thanks 

Answer (score 0):

A gate is simply a collection of transistors connected.

I will present 3 basic logic gates AND,OR and NOT.By using those logic gates we can make even more complicated such as NAND,NOR and XOR.

AND:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYIpiW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When A and B both have voltage bigger than the voltage of the point where the arrow points(0.7V bigger) electrons flow from the negative terminal of the battery to the positive terminal of the battery.

If one of A or B dont have voltage bigger than the voltage of the point where the arrow points(0.7V bigger) electrons don't flow from the negative terminal of the battery to the positive terminal of the battery.

OR:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZ46AT.png)</sup>

If one of A or B  have voltage bigger than the voltage of the point where the arrow points(0.7V bigger) electrons flow from the negative terminal of the battery to the positive terminal of the battery.

If none of A or B dont have voltage bigger than the voltage of the point where the arrow points(0.7V bigger) electrons don't flow from the negative terminal of the battery to the positive terminal of the battery.

NOT:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqqhbp.png)</sup>

When A  has voltage bigger than the voltage of the point where the arrow points(0.7V bigger) electrons dont flow through the R1 resistor( due to KVL I assume you know that).

If A doesnt have voltage bigger than the voltage of the point where the arrow points(0.7V bigger) electrons  flow through the R1 resistor( because there is no other way to go from the negative terminal to the positive terminal).

Hope you find it helpful.

Let's zoom in the transistor to see more in detail:

[image]

This is a BJT transistor.If we apply a voltage bigger than 0.7V to the middle layer then electrons will move to the middle layer and holes will move to the bottom layer

[image]

Some electrons and holes will recombine, leaving an excess of electrons in the middle layer. Now the middle layer is incredible  tiny so electrons have a good chance of going to the upper layer and then from there flow in the circuit.

[image]

If we apply a voltage less than 0.7V then electrons won't travel from the bottom layer to the middle layer and holes won't travel from the middle layer to the bottom layer and this proccess cannot be done so no electrons can flow in the circuit.

That is the general idea.And it is a very simplified version of reality but it is good for an introduction to the subject.

Images taken from: [Transistor working | Class 12 (India) | Physics | Khan Academy on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZXsmVBHqaf8)

Comment: I suggest you add a picture or diagram of a physical MOSFET on silicon. so that the "under a microscope" part about what everything physically is, is answered. Also, label the output and reference nodes your schematics. It is not obvious to a beginner what the output is read across

Comment: These schematic diagrams are essentially useless for understanding how real gates work on real chips.

Comment: @DaveTweed I think it gives a rough idea. What is it you were looking for specifically?

Comment: These schematics don't make sense. No one has ever made logic gates like this.

Comment: Ok instead of saying my answer is bad why don't you make your answer?

Comment: thanks everyone and Helena for the comments. From what I understand, electrons go through resistor before gate if point A has less voltage than the arrow. I assume there is some physics reason for it. I suppose semiconductor physics is the way to go here

Comment: @SamGibson this is indeed from Khan Academy.

Comment: Ok Af91 i will include the case where the voltage of the middle layer is less than the voltage of the bottom layer.

Comment: Conventionally, we draw schematics with the positive rail at the top, the negative or ground at the bottom, and have the signal flowing from left to right.  The way you've drawn the schematics hurts my head - and they don't make sense without an output shown (then you'd see they don't make sense anyway.)

Comment: Af91 why everyone and Helena? Because I am girl this doesnt mean I dont belong to anyone.

Comment: Helena - I believe that he thanked you by name because you provided the answer - lots of work. The other people "everyone else" provided brief comments. So you were single out for specific thanks.